# jquery object expected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I have a problem with jquery error in IE6-8 when clicking on button removing input. 
The webbrowser gives me error message "object expected"

Any tips to solve this kind of problem? I can share with my code which adds and removes inputs and it also counts the number of all inputs. I have used php to give information about current existing inputs with values. Is it possible that it is not working because of any syntax mistake in the jquery script or is it just wrong to include CDN for older IE webrowsers?

Thanks for all possible helps or tips.

It includes Google CDN:

```
<script language = "javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

this is the whole jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxTags = 20;
    var tagsDiv = $("#newTagsDiv");
    var addTag = $("#addTagButton");
    var removeTag = $("#removeTagButton");

    var x = tagsDiv.length + <? php print $tagNumber; ?> -1;
    var tagNumber = <? php print $tagNumber; ?> -1;

    $(addTag).click(function (e) {
        if (x <= maxTags) {
            tagNumber++;
            $(tagsDiv).append('<div id="tagDiv' + tagNumber + '"><span class="tagNumber">' + tagNumber + '.</span><input type="text" name="tag' + tagNumber + '" id="tag' + tagNumber + '" size="20" value=""/></div>');
            x++;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(removeTag).click(function (e) {
        if (x > 1) {
            $('#tagDiv' + tagNumber).remove();
            x--;
            tagNumber--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Use IE's dev tools & debugger to find the problem.

Comment: What line does it throw that error on?

Comment: what version of jQuery? Use development version to find exactly what method is causing issue...then look in your code for what migt use that

Comment: it throws error on line 175. I will try to look at the version of jquery. it is the version 1.10 probably

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<script language = "javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And have it inside of your `head`.

This seems to be a common problem in newer versions of IE, that is, it actually forced you to do it the "proper way".

Comment: @the removed comment: Unfortunately not the actual problem but this should be the answer to the question.

Comment: It seems like it has still the same behaviour. I had written script type before I tried script language... both act the same unfortunately.

Comment: Using text/javascript?